# How to save the result of EXEC(@SQL) in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone please help me out on how can I save the result of `EXEC (@SQL)` In a variable so that I can use it in a update statement

```
--Using SQL SERVER 2018
DECLARE
@MasterID   NVARCHAR(30), 
@INPUTXML   XML 

SET @MasterID = 't_Product'

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @SharedOn   DateTime,
            @TypeID     XML ,
            @SQL        NVARCHAR(500),
            @ErrMsg     NVARCHAR(200)


    CREATE TABLE #TypeID
    (
        ID  NVARCHAR(50)
    )

    SELECT  @SharedOn   = SharedOn,
            @TypeID     = TypeID
    FROM    t_MasterDataShareControl 
    WHERE   MasterID    = @MasterID


    INSERT INTO #TypeID
    (   
        ID
    )
    SELECT          
            NULLIF(TypeID.x.value('ID[1]','nvarchar(250)'),'')
    FROM    @TypeID.nodes('/dt_TypeID/dt_ID') AS TypeID(x)

    

    IF @MasterID IN ('t_Product','t_WFAdvRule') AND @TypeID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL =  'SELECT * 
                     FROM ' + @MasterID + 
                    ' WHERE ISNULL(ModifiedOn,CreatedOn)'+ '>' + concat(char(39),@SharedOn,char(39))
    END
    IF @MasterID IN ('t_SystemCodeDetail','t_UserCodeDetail','t_BankUserCode','t_BranchUserCode' ) AND @TypeID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @SQL =  'SELECT * 
                 FROM ' + @MasterID +
                ' WHERE ISNULL(ModifiedOn,CreatedOn) >' + concat(char(39),@SharedOn,char(39)) +
                'AND    ID IN ( SELECT  * 
                                FROM    #TypeID )'
    END

    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FOR XML PATH('+ concat(char(39),@MasterID,char(39)) + '),ROOT(''InputXML'')'

    EXEC (@SQL)



    ENDSTMT:

    DROP TABLE #TypeID
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

I tried it , but no results

```
SET @SQL =  'SET @myVar = ( SELECT * FROM ' + @MasterID + 
                    ' WHERE ISNULL(ModifiedOn,CreatedOn)'+ '>' + concat(char(39),@SharedOn,char(39)) +' )'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@myVar NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @myVar OUT

SELECT @myVar
```

I also tried inserting in temp table, but then I get:

> The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you need to assign your output variable to a variable in your outer scope. e.g. `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@myVar NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @MyLocalVar = @myVar OUT`. `@MyVar` only exists in your dynamic SQL scope.

Comment: When you tried it and got no results... was the `t_MasterDataShareControl.TypeID` value for the `t_Product` row a `null`?

Comment: `SET @myVar = ( SELECT * FROM` - are you trying to assign a value from the SQL here to the variable? If so, you are actually trying to assign all columns from all matching rows to a scalar variable, and this isn't possible unless there is only one column and only one matching row. Or are you trying to return that whole `SELECT` as a string? If you are trying to generate a string, you need to make it a string, e.g. `SET @SQL = N'SET @myVar = ''SELECT * FROM ...'';'` and then as Dale pointed out treat it like a proper output parameter.

Comment: The update statement will have to be part of the eventual dynamic SQL ... maybe you could show exactly what update statement you're trying to end up with, it might make it easier to help you.

Comment: [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i0XezhtO).

Comment: Thanks @Dalek , I did not assign the output variable to a variable in outer scope. Now its working properly